# How do i get rid of the vertical line appearing in the AceEditor component?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-ace

I am using react-ace in my react component

This is the example they provide at npmjs (plus a little bit of costumisation):

```
import React from "react";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "brace/mode/python";
import "brace/theme/github";

function onChange(newValue) {
  console.log("change", newValue);
}

function CustomAceEditor() {
  return (
    <AceEditor
      mode="python"
      theme="github"
      onChange={onChange}
      name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
      editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
      width="100%"
    />
  );
}

export default CustomAceEditor;
```

When i compile and execute this code i get the result in the following picture
[image]

But as you can see there is vertical line in the view.. how do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

I think that line is the Print Margin for the editor. There is a flag to remove it:

```
showPrintMargin={false}
```

In your case:

```
<AceEditor
  mode="python"
  theme="github"
  onChange={onChange}
  showPrintMargin={false}
  name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
  editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
  width="100%"
/>
```